# Nesting of SQL COUNT and COUNT DISTINCT ... in other words, how do I nest or COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, rank

**This is for SQL2010

Trying to find how many students took each PGM (ie. Program)

Need to produce a report that has 5 columns

1. Program Name
2. Program Count
3. Program Ranking
4. Student Count
5. Student Ranking

Results

PGMs/Programs COUNT is fine.

And so is the PGM Ranking

But Student COUNTS and Student Rankings are 1.

Everyone of them is "1". :(

I'm thinking I need to SELECT within a SELECT (or I don't really know SQL that well)

```
SELECT TOP 100
       T.PGM AS Program, 
       COUNT(*) AS ProgramCount,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as ProgramRanking,
       T.SID AS 'StudentID', 
       COUNT(DISTINCT 'StudentID') AS ProgramCount,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT 'StudentID') DESC) as StudentRanking

FROM StudentPrograms T
WHERE T.PGM <>'unknown' AND
      T.CreateDate > '2015-10-01' AND
      T.CreateDate < '2015-11-01'  -- We do LIKE Halloween :)
GROUP BY  T.PGM
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Thank you again

Comment: can you share the columns in the table(s) , also please share few sample rows.

Comment: Remove this line  "T.SID AS 'StudentID'," from your query and then count on t.sid instead of 'StudentID'

Comment: ThanksI tried t.SID instead of StudentID and this is what I get

Comment: Program=ENG101, PGMCount=1629, ProgramRanking=1, StudentCount=1, Student Rank=1

Comment: And this is the same for BIO101, CHEM102, etc ... I get the correct COUNT of the PGM but not of the students taking the course.  And oof note, I have a variable-typo in my original question but I fixed it in my real SQL. Thank you again (and I'm not sure why Ican't use carriage returns in this editor :().  Thanks again

Comment: does your query looks like this now : 
`SELECT 
       T.PGM AS Program, 
       COUNT(*) AS ProgramCount,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as ProgramRanking,
       COUNT(DISTINCT t.sid) AS ProgramCount,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT t.sid) DESC) as StudentRanking`

Comment: It does now.  It works.  Thank you so much.  Tons of thanks :)

Comment: Please mark it as an answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to  :

```
SELECT 
 T.PGM AS Program, 
 COUNT(*) AS ProgramCount, 
 RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as ProgramRanking, 
 COUNT(DISTINCT t.sid) AS ProgramCount, 
 RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT t.sid) DESC) as StudentRanking
FROM StudentPrograms T
WHERE T.PGM <>'unknown' AND
      T.CreateDate > '2015-10-01' AND
      T.CreateDate < '2015-11-01'  -- We do LIKE Halloween :)
GROUP BY  T.PGM
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```